# javac: incompatible types: Mono<Object> cannot be converted

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mono, project-reactor

Could anyone explain why the `mono1()` method shows no errors in Eclipse, and runs in Eclipse, but does not compile with Maven or `javac`? And why the `mono2()` method is ok in both Eclipse and Maven/`javac`?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class IncompatibleTypes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mono1().doOnNext(a -> System.out.println("mono1: " + a)).subscribe();
        mono2().doOnNext(a -> System.out.println("mono2: " + a)).subscribe();
    }

    static Mono<A> mono1() {
        return Mono.just("mono1")
                .flatMap(flatMapper(A.class))
                .doOnError(System.err::println); // Maven/javac errors on this line
                                                 // Eclipse is fine with it
    }

    static Mono<A> mono2() {
        Mono<A> mono = Mono.just("mono2")
                .flatMap(flatMapper(A.class)); // compiles fine in Eclipse, Maven, javac
        mono = mono.doOnError(System.err::println);
        return mono;
    }

    static <R> Function<? super String, ? extends Mono<? extends R>> flatMapper(Class<R> clazz) {
        return (str) -> {
            A a = new A(str);
            return Mono.just((R) a);
        };
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class A {
        private String name;
    }
}
```

This is the error from Maven and/or `javac`:

```
IncompatibleTypes.java:16: error: incompatible types: Mono<Object> cannot be converted to Mono<A>
                .doOnError(System.err::println);
```

[`doOnError()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnError-java.util.function.Consumer-) should return `Mono<T>`, and `T` should not be `Object` in my example.

There is no error in Eclipse, and when I hover over `doOnError` in Eclipse, it shows the expected type of `Mono<A>` (and not `Mono<Object>`):

[image]

- **Eclipse version**: Spring Tools Suite Version: 3.9.5.RELEASE.
- **Maven version**: 3.5.0
- **maven-compiler-plugin**: 3.7.0
- **javac version**: 1.8.0_171

Comment: Does javac give you any raw type warnings too?

Comment: @AndyTurner - nope, just the compiler error.

Comment: Can you put in an explicit type hint: `.<A>doOnError`? Or maybe it should be on the `flatMap`.

Comment: Adding that gives a warning in Eclipse `Unused type arguments for the non generic method doOnError(Consumer<? super Throwable>) of type 
 Mono<IncompatibleTypes.A>; it should not be parameterized with arguments <IncompatibleTypes.A>`, and the compiler error remains in javac.

Comment: The TL;DR is that the type inference rules are crazily complicated, and there are differences in the implementations of javac and eclipse (numerous questions on SO about differences between the two). I don't think there's a good "reason"; just go with the workarounds you've found.

Comment: _"it shows the expected type of Mono<A>"_ How can this be expected when the signatures says `? extends R` and not `R`. Wildcards in return values don't make much sense.